# Python: Finding differences between elements of a list

Tags: python, list

Given a list of numbers, how does one find differences between every (`i`)-th elements and its (`i+1`)-th?

Is it better to use a `lambda` expression or maybe a list comprehension?

For example:

Given a list `t=[1,3,6,...]`, the goal is to find a list `v=[2,3,...]` because `3-1=2`, `6-3=3`, etc.

Answer (score 202, accepted):

```
>>> t
[1, 3, 6]
>>> [j-i for i, j in zip(t[:-1], t[1:])]  # or use itertools.izip in py2k
[2, 3]
```

Comment: In case you need absolute differences,  `[abs(j-i) for i,j in zip(t, t[1:])]`

Comment: In case you want to make it more efficient: `list(itertools.starmap(operator.sub, zip(t[1:], t)))` (after importing `itertools` and `operator`).

Comment: Actually simply `list(map(operator.sub, t[1:], t[:-1]))` will do.

Answer (score 151):

The other answers are correct but if you're doing numerical work, you might want to consider numpy. Using numpy, the answer is:

```
v = numpy.diff(t)
```

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks!
`np.diff([2,4,9])` would be `[2,5]`

Comment: Would this be more efficient than the `zip` version?

Answer (score 43):

If you don't want to use `numpy` nor `zip`, you can use the following solution:

```
>>> t = [1, 3, 6]
>>> v = [t[i+1]-t[i] for i in range(len(t)-1)]
>>> v
[2, 3]
```

Answer (score 24):

Starting in `Python 3.10`, with the new [`pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/itertools.html?highlight=pairwise#itertools.pairwise) function it's possible to slide through pairs of elements and thus map on rolling pairs:

```
from itertools import pairwise

[y-x for (x, y) in pairwise([1, 3, 6, 7])]
# [2, 3, 1]
```

---

The intermediate result being:

```
pairwise([1, 3, 6, 7])
# [(1, 3), (3, 6), (6, 7)]
```

Comment: Lol, I've had something similar in my common functions for ages now. I called my implementation "chunker", but pairwise has a nice sound to it. Very useful.

Answer (score 17):

You can use [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) and `zip` to efficiently build the result:

```
from itertools import tee
# python2 only:
#from itertools import izip as zip

def differences(seq):
    iterable, copied = tee(seq)
    next(copied)
    for x, y in zip(iterable, copied):
        yield y - x
```

Or using [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) instead:

```
from itertools import islice

def differences(seq):
    nexts = islice(seq, 1, None)
    for x, y in zip(seq, nexts):
        yield y - x
```

You can also avoid using the `itertools` module:

```
def differences(seq):
    iterable = iter(seq)
    prev = next(iterable)
    for element in iterable:
        yield element - prev
        prev = element
```

All these solution work in constant space if you don't need to store all the results and support infinite iterables.

---

Here are some micro-benchmarks of the solutions:

```
In [12]: L = range(10**6)

In [13]: from collections import deque
In [15]: %timeit deque(differences_tee(L), maxlen=0)
10 loops, best of 3: 122 ms per loop

In [16]: %timeit deque(differences_islice(L), maxlen=0)
10 loops, best of 3: 127 ms per loop

In [17]: %timeit deque(differences_no_it(L), maxlen=0)
10 loops, best of 3: 89.9 ms per loop
```

And the other proposed solutions:

```
In [18]: %timeit [x[1] - x[0] for x in zip(L[1:], L)]
10 loops, best of 3: 163 ms per loop

In [19]: %timeit [L[i+1]-L[i] for i in range(len(L)-1)]
1 loops, best of 3: 395 ms per loop

In [20]: import numpy as np

In [21]: %timeit np.diff(L)
1 loops, best of 3: 479 ms per loop

In [35]: %%timeit
    ...: res = []
    ...: for i in range(len(L) - 1):
    ...:     res.append(L[i+1] - L[i])
    ...: 
1 loops, best of 3: 234 ms per loop
```

Note that:

- `zip(L[1:], L)` is equivalent to `zip(L[1:], L[:-1])` since `zip` already terminates on the shortest input, however it avoids a whole copy of `L`.
- Accessing the single elements by index is *very* slow because every index access is a method call in python
- `numpy.diff` is *slow* because it has to first convert the `list` to a `ndarray`. Obviously if you *start* with an `ndarray` it will be *much* faster:

  ```
  In [22]: arr = np.array(L)

  In [23]: %timeit np.diff(arr)
  100 loops, best of 3: 3.02 ms per loop
  ```

Comment: in the second solution, `islice(seq, 1, None)` instead of `islice(seq, 1, len(seq))` makes it work with infinite iterables

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest using

```
v = np.diff(t)
```

this is simple and easy to read.

But if you want `v` to have the same length as `t` then

```
v = np.diff([t[0]] + t) # for python 3.x
```

or

```
v = np.diff(t + [t[-1]])
```

FYI: this will only work for lists.

for numpy arrays

```
v = np.diff(np.append(t[0], t))
```

Comment: nice answer, you can also use the prepend keyword though to ensure the same length, see answer below, which I think is a little neater

Answer (score 6):

Using the `:=` walrus operator available in Python 3.8+:

```
>>> t = [1, 3, 6]
>>> prev = t[0]; [-prev + (prev := x) for x in t[1:]]
[2, 3]
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok. I think I found the proper solution:

```
v = [x[0]-x[1] for x in zip(t[1:],t[:-1])]
```

Comment: ya its good, but I think it should have been
    v = [x[0]-x[1] for x in zip(t[1:], t[:-1])] 
for sorted list!

Answer (score 4):

A functional approach:

```
>>> import operator
>>> a = [1,3,5,7,11,13,17,21]
>>> map(operator.sub, a[1:], a[:-1])
[2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4]
```

Using generator:

```
>>> import operator, itertools
>>> g1,g2 = itertools.tee((x*x for x in xrange(5)),2)
>>> list(itertools.imap(operator.sub, itertools.islice(g1,1,None), g2))
[1, 3, 5, 7]
```

Using indices:

```
>>> [a[i+1]-a[i] for i in xrange(len(a)-1)]
[2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is what the numpy diff command does anyway, but just for completeness you can simply difference the sub-vectors:

```
from numpy import array as a
a(x[1:])-a(x[:-1])
```

In addition, I wanted to add these solutions to generalizations of the question:

**Solution with periodic boundaries**

Sometimes with numerical integration you will want to difference a list with periodic boundary conditions (so the first element calculates the difference to the last.  In this case the numpy.roll function is helpful:

```
v-np.roll(v,1)
```

**Solutions with zero prepended**

Another [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ediff1d.html?highlight=ediff#numpy.ediff1d) solution (just for completeness) is to use

```
numpy.ediff1d(v)
```

This works as numpy.diff, but only on a vector (it flattens the input array). It offers the ability to prepend or append numbers to the resulting vector.  This is useful when handling accumulated fields that is often the case fluxes in meteorological variables (e.g. rain, latent heat etc), as you want a resulting list of the same length as the input variable, with the first entry untouched.

Then you would write

```
np.ediff1d(v,to_begin=v[0])
```

Of course, you can also do this with the np.diff command, in this case though you need to prepend zero to the series with the prepend keyword:

```
np.diff(v,prepend=0.0)
```

All the above solutions return a vector that is the same length as the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert the difference into an easily readable transition matrix using

```
v = t.reshape((c,r)).T - t.T
```

Where `c` = number of items in the list and `r` = 1 since a list is basically a vector or a 1d array.

Answer (score -1):

My way

```
>>>v = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>>[v[i] - v[i-1] for i, value in enumerate(v[1:], 1)]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Using `enumerate` is wasteful because you're not using `value`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16714453/832230