# efficiently subtract item in list from its sibling

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [pairwise traversal of a list or tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849625/pairwise-traversal-of-a-list-or-tuple)

I have this list: `[(0, 'set'), (1, 'of'), (4, 'coloured'),(5, 'eels')]`

I would like to efficiently iterate and achieve item+1[0] - item[0]

as in 1 - 0, 4 - 1, 5 - 4

I currently have:

```
search_list = [(0, 'set'), (1, 'of'), (4, 'coloured')] 
[search_list[i+1][0]-search_list[i][0] for i in range(0,len(search_list)-1)]
```

But my code is not as efficient as I would like. Can map and lambda achieve the outcome?

I would like to avoid importing modules (but, of course, will if lambda and map cannot achieve this)

Comment: I just noticed you asked about a better performing solution.  You won't find anything significantly better than what you have unless you use NumPy (specifically, `numpy.diff()`).

Comment: The accepted answer in the question that Sven mentions should work here too, you just need to access an element of a tuple as well.

Comment: Usually map with lamba is slower than list comprehensions. Also if you are using python 2 use 'xrange' instead of 'range'. That creates generator instead of list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about being efficient:

```
>>> search_list = [(0, 'set'), (1, 'of'), (4, 'coloured'),(5, 'eels')]
>>> [y[0]-x[0] for x,y in zip(search_list,search_list[1:])]
[1, 3, 1]
```

`itertools` version by popular demand:

```
>>> from itertools import izip, islice
>>> search_list = [(0, 'set'), (1, 'of'), (4, 'coloured'),(5, 'eels')]
>>> [y[0]-x[0] for x,y in izip(search_list, islice(search_list, 1, None))]
[1, 3, 1]
```

Comment: You only need to slice once -- the longer list will just have its last item ignored by `zip`.

Comment: thanks. timeit shows:

mine at 1000 runs: 0.00149552307798s
yours at 1000 runs0.00224554247503s

Can the answer be improved based on @agf comment?

Comment: @rikAtee Is it actually a bottleneck? If not, don't worry about it. `[y[0]-x[0] for x,y in zip(search_list,search_list[1:])]` should be slightly faster than with the extra slicing, and use less memory, but it rarely matters. If memory useage is important, you can use your version or use `itertools` -- `izip` instead of `zip` and `islice(1, len(search_list))` instead of `search_list[1:]`.

Comment: Mine was only an attempt to make it efficient in terms of easy to read, type and maintain.