# Python, is there a function that give me the cumulate sum?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, list, django-models

I have the following list value:

```
iva_versamenti_totale={'Liquidazione IVA': [sum(t) for t in zip(*iva_versamenti.values())],}
```

I want to obtain about the `iva_versamenti_totale` variable the following sum:

```
p0, p1+p0, p2+p1, p3+p2 and so on...
```

Ad example:

```
iva_versamenti_totale = {'Liquidazione IVA': [1,2,3,4,5],}
result={'Totals': [1,3,5,7,9],}
```

**EDIT**

I have tried the following code:

```
iva_versamenti_totale = [1,2,3,4,5]

results = [*map(sum, zip(iva_versamenti_totale , [0]+iva_versamenti_totale ))]
```

But if I try

```
iva_versamenti_totale = [1,0,0,0]
```

I want to obtain `[1,1,1,1]`, instead I obtain [1,1,0,0]

Comment: This is not a cumulative sum. This is a sum of pairs.

Comment: Better duplicate target: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849625/pairwise-traversal-of-a-list-or-tuple

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pairwise traversal of a list or tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849625/pairwise-traversal-of-a-list-or-tuple)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another version:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]

s = [*map(sum, zip(l, [0]+l))]

print(s)
```

Prints:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: I have solved it with your answer. Just a last questio: if I want to set a filter that set at zero the negative value? Ad example if my print is `[ 1, 3, 5, -3 ]`give me `[ 1, 3, 5, 0 ] ??

Comment: @Jfix91 if you want to set negative values in list to `0` you can do for example `print([max(0, v)  for v in [1, 3, 5, -3]])`

Comment: oKEY Thanks. I have noticed that your code don't save the values of previous i. Ad example: if I have `[1,0,0,0,0]` the result may be `[1,1,1,1,1]` instead [1,1,0,0,0]

Answer (score 0):

You can try like :

```
a =  [1,2,3,4,5]
[a[i]+a[i-1] if i!=0 else a[i] for i in range(len(a))]
```