# Difference between consecutive elements in list

Tags: python, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python - Differences between elements of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400840/python-differences-between-elements-of-a-list)

I have a list and I want to find difference between consecutive elements:

```
a = [0, 4, 10, 100]
find_diff(a)
>>> [4,6,90]
```

How would you code find_diff() function? I can code this with "for" iterator but I am sure there are very simple ways to do it with a simple one liner.

Comment: hmm, I was going to accept the first answer but I see that it is deleted now.

Comment: As well it should have been, since that question asks **exactly the same thing**.

Comment: so should I delete this question? I couldn't find that one in search before asking

Comment: Don't delete it. This will get closed as a dup, so no more answers can be added. In general, it's good to have multiple dups which point to a single, canonical Q&A. Since there is more than one way to word a question, having multiple (differently-worded) questions pointing to a master Q&A makes it easier to find the master in the future.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You could utilize [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate), [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> a = [0, 4, 10, 100]

# basic enumerate without condition:
>>> [x - a[i - 1] for i, x in enumerate(a)][1:]
[4, 6, 90]

# enumerate with conditional inside the list comprehension:
>>> [x - a[i - 1] for i, x in enumerate(a) if i > 0]
[4, 6, 90]

# the zip version seems more concise and elegant:
>>> [t - s for s, t in zip(a, a[1:])]
[4, 6, 90]
```

Performance-wise, there seems to be not too much variance:

```
In [5]: %timeit [x - a[i - 1] for i, x in enumerate(a)][1:]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.34 µs per loop

In [6]: %timeit [x - a[i - 1] for i, x in enumerate(a) if i > 0]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.11 µs per loop

In [7]: %timeit [t - s for s, t in zip(a, a[1:])]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.1 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 20):

Use [`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) (Python 3.10+):

```
>>> from itertools import pairwise
>>> a = [0, 4, 10, 100]
>>> [y - x for x, y in pairwise(a)]
[4, 6, 90]
```

For Python 3.9 and older you can use the [recipe for `pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/itertools.html#recipes) from the itertools documentation:

```
from itertools import izip, tee
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)
```

Comment: That's completely unnecessary. See [Python - Differences between elements of a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400840/python-differences-between-elements-of-a-list).

Comment: @Matt Ball:  Many iterators can be called "unnecessary", but once defined, they're darn useful for common idioms.  Why ask the reader to puzzle out a zip of two slices when we can assign a useful name to the idea like `pairwise`.  I don't think I'm alone in thinking this as I lifted the example directly from the docs.

Comment: +! This version works for arbitrary generators, which can't be sliced/indexed.

Comment: This function is available in itertools Python 3.10 and above

Answer (score 6):

```
[x - a[i-1] if i else None for i, x in enumerate(a)][1:]
```