# Loop for Subtracting within Array Elements

Tags: python, for-loop, numpy

I am a newbie using Python and Numpy.
I thought this would be simple and probably is.
I have an array of times.
For example:

```
times = (0.5,  0.75,  1.5)
```

This array will vary in size depending on the files loaded.

I simply want to find the difference in time between each subsequent element.

```
0.75 - 0.5
then
1.5 - 0.75
```

and so for the number of elements in the array.
Then I put each result into one column.

I have tried various for loops but unable to do it.  There must be a simple way?

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: Well, what *have* you tried? Incidentally, this is a common problem. Search on here or on google.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - Differences between elements of a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400840/python-differences-between-elements-of-a-list)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314241/difference-between-consecutive-elements-in-list

Comment: Thanks Marcin, everything I looked at online or tried didn't answer this case (bad searching I guess).  The trouble I had was getting indiv. elements to do calculations on each other over an array.  Everything was about one element, not two.  Your links are very helpful as are the other suggestions here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([0.5,  0.75,  1.5])
>>> np.diff(a)
array([ 0.25,  0.75])
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

First, note that for most everyday uses, you probably won't require an array (which is a special datatype in Numpy). Python's workhorse means of data storage is the list, and is definitely worth reading up on if you're coming from a more rigid programming language. Lists are actually defined using square brackets:

```
times = [ 0.5,  0.75,  1.5 ]
```

Then, with special syntax called a list comprehension, we can create a new list that has (length-1) elements. This expression automatically figures out the size of the list needed.

```
diffs = [ times[i] - times[i-1] for i in range(1, len(times)) ]
```

And for the sample data provided, returns:

```
[0.25, 0.75]
```

Answer (score 1):

Or how about these (all variants on the same theme):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0.5,  0.75,  1.5])
b = a[1:]-a[:-1]
print (b)
```

or without numpy:

```
a=[0.5,  0.75,  1.5]
a1=a[1:]
a2=a[:-1]
b=[ aa-a2[i] for i,aa in enumerate(a1) ]
```

or

```
a=[0.5,  0.75,  1.5]
c=[x-y for x,y in zip(a[1:],a[:-1])]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
diffs = [b-a for a, b in zip(times[:-1], times[1:])]
[0.25, 0.75]
```

This approach requires no numpy, simple Python. Subtracting

```
times[1:]
(0.75, 1.5)

times[:-1]
(0.5, 0.75)
```

from each other

Answer (score 0):

this should do it.

```
import numpy as np


times = np.array([0.5,0.75,1.5,2.0])
diff_times = np.zeros(len(times)-1,dtype =float)

for i in range(1,len(times)):
    diff_times[i-1] = times[i] - times[i-1]

print diff_times
```

Answer (score 0):

very basic:

```
liste = [1,3,8]
difference = []
for i in range(len(liste)-1):
    diffs = abs(liste[i] - liste[i+1])
    difference.append(diffs)

print difference
```