# What is the pythonic method to produce a list of the differences between the neighbouring values of an original list

Tags: python, list, subtraction

I have a list and want to know if the following can be done in Python **without** adding extra libraries to improve my code.

I want to get a list of the differences between elements of a list.

```
orig_list = [12, 27,31,55,95]

#desired output
spacings =[15, 4, 24,40]
```

I know I can do it by making a second list and subtracting it, I just wondered if there was another/better way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between consecutive elements in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314241/difference-between-consecutive-elements-in-list)

Comment: The more popular one is actually https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400840/finding-differences-between-elements-of-a-list.

Comment: Hi AMC, the 'more popular one' would have answered my question, I must say I especially liked Drizzt's solution (below) although there is a similarly syntaxes answer on one of those you showed, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension and `zip`:

```
[j-i for i,j in zip(orig_list[:-1], orig_list[1:])]
# [15, 4, 24, 40]
```

Though if NumPy is an option you have `np.diff`:

```
np.diff(orig_list)
# array([15,  4, 24, 40])
```

Comment: Hi yalu, I knew how to do it in numpy but couldn't think how I could do it in regular python, this works and saves importing a library for one operation, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is also possible with list comprehension, without using `zip`. Just iterate over the list elements from index 1 to n:

`[orig_list[i]- orig_list[i-1] for i in range(1, len(orig_list))]`