# Method to get the max distance (step) between values in python?

Tags: python, list

Given an list of integers does exists a default method find the max distance between values?

So if I have this array

```
[1, 3, 5, 9, 15, 30]
```

The max step between the values is 15. Does the list object has a method for do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, `list` objects have no standard "adjacent differences" method or the like. However, using the `pairwise` function mentioned in the [`itertools` recipes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)
```

...you can (concisely *and* efficiently) define

```
>>> max(b-a for (a,b) in pairwise([1, 3, 5, 9, 15, 30]))
15
```

Comment: so easy :) I think that is one of the best answer :)

Comment: How to import itertools's `pairwise` function ? Or do we have to include the implementation provided in the docs  Recipes.

Comment: I also fail to import it. I use "import itertools" and then "itertools.pairwise" but it always throws an "AttributeError" while e.g. "itertools.combinations" works fine.

Comment: @TanveerAlam, @Cleb Indeed, `pairwise` is not a function provided by the `itertools` module: it's an example mentioned in the "recipes" section I linked. I now included the definition in this answer to make it (the answer) more self-contained.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: Thanks for the edit, I was confused when I failed to import it. It is not a default function UsiUsi asked for but seems kind of efficient :)

Comment: Unfortunately I get this error NameError: global name 'tee' is not defined

Comment: @UsiUsi `tee` is a function from `itertools`. If you just did `import itertools` you would need to use `itertools.tee` (and `itertools.izip`).

Answer (score 2):

No, but it's trivial to code:

```
last = data[0]
dist = 0
for i in data[1:]:
    dist = max(dist, i-last)
    last = i
return dist
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
>>> s = [1, 3, 5, 9, 15, 30]
>>> max(x[0] - x[1] for x in zip(s[1:], s))
15
```

This uses [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip). It computes the difference between all consecutive elements and returns the max of those.

Answer (score 2):

```
l=[1, 3, 5, 9, 15, 30]
max([j-i for i, j in zip(l[:-1], l[1:])])
```

That is using pure python and gives you the desired output "15".

If you like to work with "numpy" you could do:

```
import numpy as np
max(np.diff(l))
```

Comment: Welcome :) Yes, it is my preferred one but since you asked for a default function, I was not sure whether it suits you.

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24894043/91757), the `numpy` version is actually pretty slow because it first has to convert the given list into an `ndarray`.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: Interesting, thanks for pointing that out! I usually don't need it in situations in which speed matters but it is good to know.

Answer (score 0):

The list object does not. However, it is pretty quick to write a function that does that:

```
def max_step(my_list):
    max_step = 0
    for ind in xrange(len(my_list)-1):
        step = my_list[ind+1] - my_list[ind]
        if step > max_step:
            max_step = step
    return max_step

>>> max_step([1, 3, 5, 9, 15, 30])
15
```

Or if you prefer even shorter:

```
max_step = lambda l: max([l[i+1] - l[i] for i in xrange(len(l)-1)])
>>> max_step([1, 3, 5, 9, 15, 30])
15
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use the `reduce()` function, but it is not that elegant as you need some way to keep track of the previous value:

```
def step(maxStep, cur):
    if isinstance(maxStep, int):
        maxStep = (abs(maxStep-cur), cur)

    return (max(maxStep[0], abs(maxStep[1]-cur)), cur)

l = [1, 3, 5, 9, 15, 30]

print reduce(step, l)[0]
```

The solution works by returing the previous value and the accumulated max calculation as a tuple for each iteration.

Also what is the expected outcome for [10,20,30,5]? Is it 10 or 25? If 25 then you need to add `abs()` to your calculation.