# python - How i can make my code shorter?

Tags: python

I have this part of code`print(int(input())-int(input()))`, but i'm need to make my code more short, and i'm looking for a way to do it.

I think, i can do `map(int, input.split(' ')`, but i don't know, how to do difference of two elements of list using functions of *Python*

Comment: Why do you need the code to be shorter? You already have a one liner.

Comment: Not sure why you need a `list` when you are just calcualting the difference between two numbers.

Comment: Don't. Short code is not better. Better code may be longer. To save a penny today, you spend a pound tomorrow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Differences between elements of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400840/python-differences-between-elements-of-a-list)

Comment: @yeger: That other question involves taking the difference of *all* consecutive pairs of numbers in a list. The solution there is definite overkill for the simple problem here. Also, the other question assumes the list is formed before the calculation, while in this question the list is formed during the process.

Comment: I need it, cause i take part in one competiton, where i must write codу with minimal simbols. In my code 32 simbols. I need 30. Spaces and enters dont count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `operator.sub` with starred unpacking of arguments from `map`

```
import operator

print(operator.sub(*map(int,"3 1".split())))  # => 2
```

it's not shorter, but it avoids to access the elements of the splitted list by index, and it's one line.

interactive variant with 2 calls to `input()` (instead of `split` on one input):

```
operator.sub(*(int(input()) for _ in range(2)))
```