# How to keep first element in list unchanged when I calculate difference between consecutive elements in list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list:

```
a = [0, 4, 10, 100]
```

I want to calculate difference between consecutive elements in list. I do this:

```
[x - a[i-1] for i, x in enumerate(a)]
```

But it brings me this result:

```
[-100, 4, 6, 90]
```

As you see first element is -100, but I want to keep first element unchanged, when I make such transformation to get this `[0, 4, 6, 90]`. How to do that?

Comment: Anything wrong with just `result[0] += a[-1]`?

Comment: You use a completely different rule for the first item. So, you might just define your output as `[first_item]` + the list of differences from one item to the next, for which there a many solutions, like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400840/python-finding-differences-between-elements-of-a-list

Comment: You have only three differences in your series.  Why do you want four elements in the result?  It's not that you "keep the first element unchanged" -- the difference process does not *change* any element; it returns a new sequence of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variation using `zip` is to just add a leading 0, since `item - 0` will be 0.

```
x = [0, 4, 10, 100]
assert [b - a for a, b in zip([0] + x, x)] == [0, 4, 6, 90]
```

If you are dealing with massive lists, running this in a loop, and care about performance, then you might not want the overhead of appending all of `a` to a new list, and can use another solution or `itertools.chain([0], a)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
a = [0, 4, 10, 100]
b = [a[i] - a[i-1] if i > 0 else a[i] for i in range(len(a))]
print(b)
# [0, 4, 6, 90]
```

Answer (score 1):

As Timur mentioned, a list comprehension will provide the most compact solution.

With zip we don't need conditionals (but we lose the first element):

```
a = [0, 4, 10, 100]
b = [a[0]] + [b-a for a, b in zip(a, a[1:])]
# [0, 4, 6, 90]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind importing numpy, this will do it very quickly for long lists:

```
import numpy as np

a = [0, 4, 10, 100]
np.diff(a, prepend=0).tolist()
```