# How do i perform operations between elements of a lists in Python using indecies?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of values like this one:

```
L = [2, 5, 6, 8, 10, 13]
```

I want to calculate the difference between the first two values and store it into a list using the list indexes. Then, calculate the difference between the second and the third and so on...

I tried a loop like this without success:

```
[(L[i+1] - L[i]) for i in L]
```

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400840/python-finding-differences-between-elements-of-a-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop, `i` holds the value, not the index, iterate over `range(len(L))` to get the indices (actually `range(len(L) - 1)` since you're getting the next value):

```
>>> [(L[i + 1] - L[i]) for i in range(len(L) - 1)]
[3, 1, 2, 2, 3]
```

In this case, `zip` can come-in handy too (iterating over values here):

```
>>> [y - x for x, y in zip(L, L[1:])]
[3, 1, 2, 2, 3]
```