# How to subtract every item of a list

Tags: python, list

I want something like this

```py
x = [100, 20, 5 , 15]
y = # the subtraction of every number in x like 100 - 20 = 80; 80 - 5 = 75; 75 - 15 = 60
print(y)
```

Output : 60

How can we make it output 60 using the list x

There is a way to do it but instead of subtraction it adds numbers and it is

```py
x = [50, 25, 25]
y = sum(x)
print(y)
```

it will print 100 but i want the oppsite of it

Comment: `x[0] - sum(x[1:])`

Comment: it is not clear what you want. `y = x[0] - sum(x[1:])`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Finding differences between elements of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400840/python-finding-differences-between-elements-of-a-list)

Comment: @Minato nope it doesnt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can take the first number, then subtract the `sum` of the remaining numbers.

```
>>> x[0] - sum(x[1:])
60
```

Answer (score 0):

You can substract all the values from the list using `reduce` function.

```py
from functools import reduce

my_list = [100, 20, 5 , 15]

result = reduce(lambda acc, current_value: acc - current_value, my_list)

print(result)
```